# zend framework: 404 only shows if layout is disabled

Tags: php, zend-framework

Locally, my error controller works just fine and sends the error message for both 404 and 500 error messages. However, when the system is live, only 500 messages are displayed, not 404's (the browser still receives the 404 header from the code, but nothing is displayed; just the browser default). If I disable the layout in the error controller, both errors are thrown.

So it seems with a layout, my 404 doesn't work. Any ideas why? My error controller is essentially the same as the one in the docs: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html but with some modifications (send email on 500, set view renderers for error type).

If I put `<? exit; ?>` at the end of my `notfound` view script, the content is shown up until then so the view is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that it is the result on an error in your 404 error controller action view script, which is suppressed, so you only get a blank page. You can try to put up a staging server, which contain the same setup and config as production except for displaying of errors to more closely see what's going on.